# This program has stopped working

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, windows-7

In a visual C++ mfc program, which I run on Wondows 7, I always get the error message **This Program Has Stopped Working** after I close the main dialog/exit the application. But it doesn't happen in Windows XP. Can anyone explain what the matter is and how to solve it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you developing this program? If yes, have you tried debugging? If no, have you asked its developers or searched for a solution online?

Comment: Yes, I did try debugging. I made sure All the resources consumed were properly de-allocated. But still I get the same problem. I'll try debugging once more. Thank you!

Comment: Is it an Application or a Console program?

Comment: It is an application using MFC.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a general problem for both vista/7. Try this, it may work:

http://thewinforums.com/topic/17070-resolvedprogram-has-stopped-working/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also I managed to do some more resource cleaning up in the program termination and now it exits without that error :) 
Thanks everyone for your help!! :D :D

Comment: old post but I hate sites that require you to login to see a post:  You are not logged in or you do not have permission to access this page.

Comment: Shame the Link is broken :( Now this answer is useless for anyone who visits this page...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the program is trying to write to a file or registry keys that require administrator access; this could occur by the program saving its settings as it shuts down. Starting with Windows Vista, Microsoft has gotten very protective with most areas of the registry and disk, and only certain places are safe to save to.