# Qt GUI has stopped working

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am developing an application for Windows, using a Windows XP machine for development. The application runs normal on Windows XP, does not have any memory leak. Running on a *Windows 7 Home Premium* machine, though, gives me a problem, but only sometimes.

I am developing a Qt application that uses OpenCV and OpenGL, and it crashes only in W7 after some time playing a video from a webcam. The error is the following:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   QtRIC.exe
Application Version:    0.0.0.0
Application Timestamp:  4e6ff3a5
Fault Module Name:  MSVCR90.dll
Fault Module Version:   9.0.30729.4940
Fault Module Timestamp: 4ca2ef57
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   00024651
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I have read [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643242/this-program-has-stopped-working) that suggest the problem is on the Windows registry, but I am not sure how to solve this problem. It just crashes (sometimes) in this version of Windows 7. Thanks!

Comment: pretty bold statement that your app has no memory leaks

Comment: @hexa, maybe, at least I checked in my part of the code and I couldn't find any memory leak. It would crash at some point also in XP, or increase the memory used, which does not happen. In any case, thanks.

Comment: Last time I used OpenGL in a Qt app, I had lots of fun chasing down texture-memory leaks, which it turned out were happening because I wasn't in the correct GL context when I freed no-longer-needed textures, and thus the texture-free calls weren't deleting the textures I thought they were.  Dunno if that has anything to do with your problem, but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. At the beginning I also had some problems with the memory leaks and OpenGL (same thing, problem with the context) but the memory usage of the program remains constant all the time and it works for XP fine. I guess (maybe I am wrong, please correct me if so) the program would increase the memory for both Operative Systems if it would have some memory leakage.

Comment: @Frank, it works fine in the computer (XP) I am using for development, so I am not sure how to do the backtrace.

Comment: @sergi: a few options: install VS on the Win7 machine so you can debug it there; install, configure and use remote debugging from the VS installed on your XP box (it can be painful to get remote debugging connected and working); or install the "Debugging Tools for Windows" package on the Win7 machine. "Debugging Tools for Windows" is freely available in the Windows SDK; you can use the  WinDbg debugger from that package, which is a GUI debugger that's maybe not as polished as the Visual Studio debugger, but is still quite easy to use and is very, very powerful.

Answer (score 2):

`c0000005` is an Access Violation, and `00024651` is an offset in MSVCR90.dll. You get an offset, and not an absolute address, because you don't know and don't care where the DLL was loaded in memory. The PDB for MSVCR90.dll will tell you what function that is.

You can just debug your program on the XP machine. Check it has the same DLL, and where it's loaded. (debug window in VS). Then add the offset (it's hex), and check the memory address in the disassembly. Assuming the PDB for MSVCR90.dll is loaded, VS will tell you what function is located at that address. You might need to scroll up a bit.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, bad week. I debugged the program on the XP machine; the problem is an access violation trying to write into 00000000. In any case, the function called does not tells me anything and I am not sure how to backtrack the problem to the root function. I also debugged the program in the Windows 7 machine but... it does not crashes either in this case. Still not sure on what is going wrong.
PS: It only crashes sometimes in the W7 machine under certain conditions.