# Basic Qt app crashes upon launch

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt

When I launch a basic Qt app within Eclipse, it crashes with a ".exe has stopped working" error.

The context :

- its the basic app obtained when creating a Qt GUI project (with a MainWindow), nothing was changed in it, haven't even added a button
- PATH has all the necessary stuff (mingw, msys, qt)
- project properties and eclipse paths should be ok too (c++, qt, mingw)
- the .pro file is ok, no file missing
- clean & rebuild, as well as relaunching eclipse doesn't resolve the problem
- upon compilation there is no error, just an ignored "**cannot lstat `ui_.h': No such file or directory**". No relevant result found when searching around that.
- if launched, stops with the afforementionned error. Details show its the app that crashed, with **error code c0000005, offset 00002cb20**. Search results tells me c0000005 is access violation, but where would that come from ? It's the basic app...
- tried to launch with eclipse being in admin mode to prevent accesss violation, didn't help
- if launched in debug mode, stops with error "**Can't find a source file at ../mingw/main.c**". I thought I forgot something when I installed mingw, so I did its setup again, but that did not create that file. No relevant search results here either.
- my setup: eclipse classic x32 with c++ & php stuff, qt 4.8, win7 x64

I'm getting lost here. I already worked with Qt under Eclipse before (on winXP and vista), got my bunch of installing problems but this one is a first. Anybody went through this already ? Any leads on how to find where the access violation is happening ? Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687270/qt-gui-has-stopped-working) makes me think it's a Qt Eclipse Integration problem, but how can I circumvent that ?

Thanks for any leads !

Comment: did you try to run 'qmake -project' and 'qmake' commands ?

Comment: "how can I circumvent that?" well: Qt Creator. If there's no good reason you must use Eclipse, Qt Creator is much more pleasant for Qt development.

Comment: @Styne666 : I'll give it a look, but I'm not fan of just looking elsewhere when there's trouble. Better to find a solution and learn something along the way.

Comment: @cbamber85 : [here you go](http://pastebin.com/iCp7NaEk)

Comment: @Jhon I don't disagree :) but I was the same until I tried Creator. As far as completely free IDEs go, it's extremely high quality and promotes the concepts embodied by the Qt framework.

Comment: I would strongly suggest QtCreator. Its a mature IDE by now, very usable. Try it! Learn something new ;-)

Comment: @Styne666 : ok, running basic projects in QtCreator doesn't work either ("The program has unexpectedly finished."), so I'm guessing there's something wrong with my Qt install somehow. I'll erase it all and do it again and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project doesn't have a `TARGET =` set in the `.pro` file.  This was probably caused by an Eclipse/Qt plugin wizard screw up, so just typing a new target may not work, other files may have to be renamed manually.

FWIW development on the Qt plugin for Eclipse was halted some time ago, building outside of Qt Creator is definitely one way of making life more difficult for yourself.

Comment: The target actually got removed when I used qmake -project, otherwise it's the project name. Anyway, I had to remove all my Qt parts and reinstall, now under QtCreator it works, I'll stick with it. Thanks for searching with me all !